# So confused over structure() in R

Tags: r, function, structure

I was looking at R-help on `structure()`. The example given by the help file is this:

```
structure(1:6, dim=2:3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
```

which creates a very nice 2 by 3 matrix. However, when I tried

```
structure(1:8, dim=2:4)
```

It won't work. Why? Another question is when should I use this `structure()` function? I don't understand why we need it, since we have `matrix()` and `data.frame()` etc.

Comment: Regarding why it didn't work, I think that the error it produces is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: "dims [product 24] do not match the length of object [8]"

Comment: It's really not very self-explanatory to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is because `2:4` yields (2,3,4). You want `c(2,4)` if you want a 2x4 matrix. That said, using `structure` to set attributes on a vector to turn in into a matrix is a really odd way of doing that. `structure` does nothing more than return a copy of the object with additional/modified attributes, in your case exploiting the fact that R represents matrices as vectors with a `dim` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array then use the 'array' function.

```
array(1:8, dim=2:4)
```

There are not many times when a beginner in R needs 'structure'.

Comment: You never said what you wanted. Use 'matrix(1:8, nrow=2)